# alphabet shift with while loops

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I am writing a program that prints the alphabet and then shifts over one. It will do this 26 times so it will end up looking like this:

```
1abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
2zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
3zxabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx
4zxyabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
```

So far I have a while loop that can do any letter and print one line of the alphabet string, but I don't know how to genralize it for one function.

Here's my code for one letter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
char a = 'a';
char h = 'h';
char z = 'z';
int start_p;
 char one = 'a';
int shift = 1;//some of these are used for later parts of my code
int end_p = 1;
int start = 0;
char two = 'a';
one = 'h';

 while(one <= z)
{
 printf("%c", one);
one = one + 1;
 }
one = ;
while(one >= a)
{
printf("%c", one);
one = one - 1;
}

return(0);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `3yzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx` and `4xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw`? If not, what do you mean by shifting?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the letters `'a'` to `'z'` are in fact consecutive, you can do some thing like this:

```
#define NUMBER_OF_LETTERS 26

main() {
    int i;
    int shift = 5;

    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_LETTERS; i++) {
        printf("%c", (i + shift) % NUMBER_OF_LETTERS + 'a');
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The modulo operator will guarantee that you are always using letters in the range `0-25 + 'a'`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a function. Note code does not include any error checking that the `start` char is valid.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printAlphabet(int start)
{
    int one = start;
    int nLettersInAlphabet = 26;
    while (nLettersInAlphabet--)
    {
        printf("%c", one);
        if (one++ == 'z')
            one = 'a';
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
printAlphabet('a');
printAlphabet('z');
printAlphabet('h');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printAlphabet(int start) 
{
    int p;
    char letter;

    for(p=0; p<26; p++){
        letter = 'a' + (((start + p) - 'a') % 26);
        printf("%c", letter);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i, start;

    for(i=26; i>0 ; i--){
        start = i + 'a';
        printAlphabet(start); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```